# Download Images for UITableViewCell using Multithread, but Cannot Load Images until Scroll the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview

I am trying to download images in the UITableViewCell using multi-thread. However, when I using the simulator to see the results, the images can not be loaded until I scroll the table view.

I have watched many examples and tutorials in StackOverFlow, but it still doesn't work at all. Actually, I download the images from the Flickr server and stored them into a cached dictionary. But I could still load the images for the first time, unless I scroll the table view and the images start to appear.

And here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    NSDictionary *photo = self.recentPhotos [indexPath.row];
    NSString *title = [photo valueForKeyPath:FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE];

    cell.textLabel.text = title;
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:18]];

    if ([self.cashedImages objectForKey:cellIdentifier] != nil) {
        cell.imageView.image = [self.cashedImages objectForKey:cellIdentifier];
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("fetch photos", 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

            NSURL *imageURL = [FlickrFetcher URLforPhoto:photo format:FlickrPhotoFormatSquare];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if ([tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row == indexPath.row) {
                    [self.cashedImages setValue:image forKey:cellIdentifier];
                    cell.imageView.image = [self.cashedImages valueForKey:cellIdentifier];
                }
            });
        });
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You 100% must use DLImageLoader ... it's incredible. stackoverflow.com/a/19115912/294884 it's a core part, essential, of making iOS apps.

Answer (score 1):

For this task probably it is better to use a library. Usually I use the SDWebImage which is very easy to use, and handle image cashing also.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

One example could be:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;
    }

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to download all the images first and cache them you shouldn't handle this in a tableviewCell. TableViewCells will start the download, when it is created -> when they become visible.

SDWebImageView cashes the images that has been downloaded before so try to add this code in the viewDidLoad method:

```
for (NSURL* url in self.recentPhotos) {
    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

    [manager downloadImageWithURL:url options:SDWebImageContinueInBackground progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
        //Your code if needed
    }];
}
```

SDWebImage caches the images based on their absolute url path.

Comment: Im sorry...This does't work for me. The images are still not loaded until I scroll them :(

Comment: Edited my answer, pls check

Answer (score 1):

**Note!**  GDImageLoader now (2016) has full, awesome, Swift version.  It is maintained on an almost daily basis - it's really perhaps the single most critical and basically perfect library in iOS. Until Apple sensibly just include caching, it's basically a must-use library.

---

GDImageLoader is incredibly simple, solid - it's the best ..

https://github.com/AndreyLunevich/DLImageLoader-iOS/tree/master/DLImageLoader

No manual, no learning curve - one command. Totally fantastic.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv
          cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    NSInteger thisRow = indexPath.row;

    MeetingsCell *cell;
    cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:
        @"CellPlayersB2" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;   // TYPICALLY NEEDED ON iPhone6+
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    NSDictionary *mtg = CLOUD.players[thisRow];

    NSString *hostText = mtg[@"host"]; etc...
    cell.whenDescrip.text = etc ...;

    NSString *imUrl = mtg[@"image"];

    __weak UIBookView *loadBooky = cell.booky;
    [DLImageLoader loadImageFromURL:imUrl
      completed:^(NSError *error, NSData *imgData)
        {
        if (loadBooky == nil) return;
        [loadBooky use:[UIImage imageWithData:imgData]];
        }];

    return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the table doesn't redraw it's content. One fix could be to save the image in self.cashedImaged (you know that a typo, right ;) ) and then instruct the UITableView to reload the single cell using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to add a Category on UIImageView and add a method something link this:

```
@interface UIImageView (Caching)
- (void)setImageWithFlickrURL:(NSURL *)url;
@end
```

And put your caching logic there.
And then in your cellForRow:indexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //...
    NSURL *imageURL = [FlickrFetcher URLforPhoto:photo format:FlickrPhotoFormatSquare];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithFlickrURL:imageURL];

    return cell;
}
```

Or, you can just use caching mechanism that provides [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)'s `UIImageView+AFNetworking`

`- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one line:

```
cell.imageView.image = [self.cashedImages valueForKey:cellIdentifier];

//add this line to make tableview redraw
[cell setNeedsLayout];
```

Comment: [cell setNeedsLayout];